# Float to double conversion getting wrong data

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Value in db is 1.36241638169457 but while fetching data using entity framework i am getting value as 1.3624163816945734 ,(in db data type is float and in entity framework data type is double ) how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

1.36241638169457
1.3624163816945734

Those are, for all intents and purposes the same number.  They may be exactly the same, and only displayed differently.  But a double-precision floating point number only has about 15 decimal digits of precision, and they agree to 15 digits.  So no problem.

Comment: Based on this value i am calculating premiums, is there any way to get exact value?

Comment: If you need more than 15 decimal digits, or exact decimal values, use DECIMAL, not binary floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Use decimal instead of double: [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

I would also consider using a decimal within the database as well, if you're dealing with this level of precision.

Edit: The following column definition could be used for such a precise number in the database:

```
DECIMAL(17, 16)
```

This accounts for the 17 digits and an accuracy to 16 decimal places. If you need further accuracy, you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: By using scaffold i got db model class in that db model i am getting double as data type , i cant change it , is there any other way to fix?

Comment: Only decimal can store a number with this kind of precision. Why can’t you change the data type? You will have to perform a schema change.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a sample column definition